# How to install Unicorn in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to know how to install the unicorn on ubuntu 10.04 and configure it and compile the source code and run the validation on console version

Comment: Welcome to SO. As per the FAQ this isn't a "real" question as you are asking how to achieve an entire process which you could easily find out how to do yourself. If, however, you are stuck with a specific part of the process that we can answer, we'd be glad to help. Might I suggest you refine your question specifying which bits you have trouble with? Which part isn't working? What don't you understand? As it stands, this question will be closed.

Comment: Please post a specific question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Brandon Tilley's guide to serving [Rails Apps with RVM, Nginx, Unicorn, and Upstart](http://brandontilley.com/2011/01/29/serving-rails-apps-with-rvm-nginx-unicorn-and-upstart.html).

Answer (score 0):

gem install unicorn doesn't work? (or sudo gem install unicorn if installing to system gems)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have make before installing the gem.

> sudo apt-get install make
>
> sudo gem install unicorn

the kgio gem requires make.